# How to search in website html via python-3.6?

Tags: python, html, search, python-requests, python-3.6

i have lot of gifts and i need create checker, that will check, if is the gift working or not --> it will search in html for some words. Im looking for "gift code invalid"

When i try to read html via urllib or requests, it will only load a small part of html. Im beginner, so im maybe doing something wrong.

my code is:

```
import requests
link = "https://discord.gift/o2uzOR7YE3CoBpGq"
r = requests.get(link)
print(r.text)
```

output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

    <!-- section:seometa -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Discord" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Discord - Free voice and text chat for gamers" />
    <meta
      property="og:description"
      content="Step up your game with a modern voice & text chat app. Crystal clear voice, multiple server and channel support, mobile apps, and more. Get your free server now!"
    /><meta property="og:image" content="https://discordapp.com/assets/ee7c382d9257652a88c8f7b7f22a994d.png" />    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@discordapp" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@discordapp" />
    <!-- endsection -->

    <link
      rel="chrome-webstore-item"
      href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lcbhdgefieegnkbopmgklhlpjjdgmbog"
    />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/0.830216ebaf585f92a484.css" integrity="sha256-qzZED1N67NuVMyWOdvhIGhtLtKnOXSg+F3HcanmdW4Q= sha512-D0iS5hrftKNpXWnvjpfujnvlabUq6K5gsHbsdvctRMtQXzdf2jvZ/JwaRHAPSb9Z5Xb2o8SBeXeMTajvtrkeRw=="><link rel="icon" href="/assets/07dca80a102d4149e9736d4b162cff6f.ico" />    <!-- section:title -->
    <title>Discord</title>
    <!-- endsection -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app-mount"></div><script nonce="NjksMjM0LDU4LDI4LDkxLDUxLDYzLDE3Mg==">window.__OVERLAY__ = /overlay/.test(location.pathname)</script><script nonce="NjksMjM0LDU4LDI4LDkxLDUxLDYzLDE3Mg==">window.GLOBAL_ENV = {
      API_ENDPOINT: '//discordapp.com/api',
      WEBAPP_ENDPOINT: '//discordapp.com',
      CDN_HOST: 'cdn.discordapp.com',
      ASSET_ENDPOINT: 'https://discordapp.com',
      WIDGET_ENDPOINT: '//discordapp.com/widget',
      INVITE_HOST: 'discord.gg',
      GIFT_CODE_HOST: 'discord.gift',
      MARKETING_ENDPOINT: '//discordapp.com',
      NETWORKING_ENDPOINT: '//router.discordapp.net',
      RELEASE_CHANNEL: 'stable',
      BRAINTREE_KEY: 'production_5st77rrc_49pp2rp4phym7387',
      STRIPE_KEY: 'pk_live_CUQtlpQUF0vufWpnpUmQvcdi',
    };</script><script nonce="NjksMjM0LDU4LDI4LDkxLDUxLDYzLDE3Mg==">!function(){if(null!=window.WebSocket){var n=function(n){try{var e=localStorage.getItem(n);return null==e?null:JSON.parse(e)}catch(n){return null}},e=n("token"),o=n("gatewayURL");if(e&&o){var r=null!=window.DiscordNative||null!=window.require?"etf":"json",t=o+"/?encoding="+r+"&v=6";void 0!==window.Uint8Array&&(t+="&compress=zlib-stream"),console.log("[FAST CONNECT] "+t+", encoding: "+r+", version: 6");var a=new WebSocket(t);a.binaryType="arraybuffer";var i=Date.now(),s={open:!1,gateway:t,messages:[]};a.onopen=function(){console.log("[FAST CONNECT] connected in "+(Date.now()-i)+"ms"),s.open=!0},a.onclose=a.onerror=function(){window._ws=null},a.onmessage=function(n){s.messages.push(n)},window._ws={ws:a,state:s}}}}();</script><script src="/assets/294f56f239ff22f62fc1.js" integrity="sha256-wTRQJKoqMfG3makS9dDuuegpcHSdaGmfoEBQUPXMdDM= sha512-OVrPyjx2akoJ6QS8OZ+9blz/ADtDHruxw4gwLsjfDVUgolO1ZtcgWbOo0Zj9JBNyzAjKOSCfoFoN9lnkF0EYCw=="></script><script src="/assets/eaa48b00154d2e7ac545.js" integrity="sha256-FRTrm1gL5gkDUoKwVuL9hrrmllKXQsZg7r5zy0Xo4bo= sha512-QZ4c5JQKE5rLJf1uGLQaHHL4NpkAigt4TtluicuMZDYDE5fiL7wkaD2CMBxr0xhOO5aNfSFCxcaqBkU/xOEggQ=="></script><script src="/assets/c73d229b094bb39f0686.js" integrity="sha256-thaBLLvK6Up+B8O7zIOF9Uv8IF+gwGuOW+WUe26l/vk= sha512-5ez2fLO3oMI1UPZDif1Szfjwz04ftTNfhWWSqM81hNhuVN7kckAAZR5a1SuQG8rgsqXwN1is53uAL5M2rz/FOg=="></script>  </body>
</html>
```

you can see in first picture, there is text "gift code invalid" in html of that site, but this string is not in python output.

https://ctrlv.cz/kKd3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into web scraping modules like `BeautifulSoup4`?

Comment: The "gift code invalid" is likely being populated by javascript, you should try using a browser automation library like `selenium`, combined with a web scraper like `BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website sends an ajax request in the background and checks the gift code for its validity. It sends a json response to indicate if the gift code is valid or not. The data is then populated by javascript.

The easiest way to get the result you want is to emulate the ajax request and get the message. You can do this without using selenium, requests-html or any other javascript rendering mechanisms and still get the output you want - to check if the gift is working or not.

```
import requests
gift_code='o2uzOR7YE3CoBpGq' #gift code here
link = f"https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/{gift_code}?with_application=true&with_subscription_plan=true"
r = requests.get(link)
print(r.json()['message'])
```

Output

```
Unknown Gift Code
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for “gift code invalid” is possibly render by js.
requests doesn’t render the js output that’s why you cannot find it.

If you're using Python 3.6 try requests-html to render the webpage with js output.

Updated example:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

link = 'https://discord.gift/o2uzOR7YE3CoBpGq'
targetString = "Gift Code Invalid"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(link)
print("Before render is call: ", targetString in r.html.text)
# sleep has to be implemented after initial the render to get the proper response
r.html.render(wait=2, sleep=1)
print("After render is call: ", targetString in r.html.text)
```

Output:

```
Before render is call:  False
After render is call:  True
Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can visit the documentation of the library for different method such as find by element, or even transform the response to lxml object after rendering:
https://html.python-requests.org/